# Passing filenames with spaces into linux functions using variables in bash script

Tags: bash, scripts, filename

I am using the following bash script to retrieve execution status of the 'cmp' command:

```
a="./textX"
b="./textX"
comm="cmp ${a} ${b}"
""${comm}""
statusX=$?
echo "Here is cmp status: ${statusX}"
```

This script works. (Variables a and b are identical in this instance for script verification purposes.)
However, some of my filenames contain spaces.
If, for example, I substitute a different file for b thus:

```
b="'./text Y'"
```

The script fails with message:

cmp:  invalid --ignore-initial value 'Y''

It looks to me as though the parser is not maintaining b as one token.  How to fix?
I've spent hours on this. I'm a newbie.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: I just realized that 'comm' is a built-in linux function, but I have verified that the assignment comm="cmp ${a} ${b}" does over-ride the built-in function, and is not the cause of my problem.

Comment: `comm` is not builtin, it's a separate binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array, quoting elements where they contain spaces or other shell-special characters, like

```
comm=(cmp "${a}" "${b}")
```

then evaluate as

```
"${comm[@]}"
```

See for example [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444949/65304)

---

FYI, your quoting in `""${comm}""` doesn't help; it just surrounds the *unquoted* variable expansion `${comm}` (which is therefore subject to word splitting and globbing) with two empty strings.

Comment: Thanks for help steeldriver.  This works and guides me to another set of skills (arrays) to pick up.